# Specifying inventory file path in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to know how we can specify the inventory file path in the ansible playbook. I'm aware of specifying the inventory path at the command line using "-i" and it works for me. But i'm looking at providing the inventory file path and the group within the ansible palybook.

Can anyone help me on this. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay. you don't specify inventory file path in Ansible playbook. However, you do specify it in your ansible.cfg file.

How do you specify the inventory file in the configuration file (i.e `ansible.cfg` ), simply open it and have

```
inventory = /path/to/your/inv/file
```

if you ask where to put the ansible.cfg file

you could create a `.ansible.cfg` in your home directory and have this info [note the `.` infront of the file name]
OR

you could create a `ansible.cfg` in your current working directory and have this info.[note `NO DOT` infront of the file name]

OR you can simply edit `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file and have this info.

OR

you can pass this configuration file path information in a environment variable `ANSIBLE_CONFIG`

Comment: You can also determine that Ansible will look for the inventory in a current location e.g in 'host' file by : inventory = $PWD/hosts

Comment: You MUST remember to precede the entry (path) in /etc/ansible.ansible.cfg file by statement: [defaults]